# How to open a file explorer from Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to open a file explorer which will be independent from the application, and will act exactly like if the user opens a file explorer from Desktop.
I do not need **QFileDialog** since I do not need to know what file will the user choose.

Comment: That sounds like something platform specific. Consider using QProcess to launch the platform specific file browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `QProcess`

```
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QProcess::startDetached("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", {});
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the desktop services, it will open the available application to handle the url you pass to it. The following opens a file browser in the root directory.

```
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///"));
```